# MassFlowSource pumping into ClosedVolume has no effect to pressure and temperature of volume in Dymola, why?

Tags: simulation, modelica, temperature, dymola, pressure

I am working a bit with Dymola now, however, while pumping (-5°C) a pulsing input of max. 100 kg/s starting at 0 kg/s into a closed volume (20°C), same medium, it has no effect to the pressure or temperature of this volume.

The simulation shows that the 100 kg/s have reached the volume, also the derivation of the temperature is visible, but not the temperature itself. Same with the pressure..

Did I miss something, or are there alternative blocks to be used? I have to stay with the ClosedVolume because of connecting with another one later on though..

Thanks in advance!!

This is the model:

[image: Model of MassFlowSource pumping into ClosedVolume]

This is the simulation output:

[image: Simulation output]

Comment: It's normally easier to understand the problem if you include the model as Modelica code (with or without annotations) and not only as an image.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I just solved this: The Input could not be designed with increasing and decreasing numbers...